# Dynamic SQL To Dynamic LINQ in VB.NET with MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I dread asking this question, because with what I've read so far I understand im gonna have to cram a lotta new things into my head. In spite of all the similiar questions(and the wide variety of answers) I thought I'd ask as nothing I've read tailors to what I need specifically enough.

I need to represent the following query using LINQ:

```
DECLARE @PurchasedInventoryItemID Int = 2
DECLARE @PurchasedInventorySectionID Int = 0
DECLARE @PurchasedInventoryItem_PurchasingCategoryID Int = 3
DECLARE @PurchasedInventorySection_PurchasingCategoryID Int = 0
DECLARE @IsActive Bit = 1
DECLARE @PropertyID Int = 2
DECLARE @PropertyValue nvarchar(1000) = 'Granny Smith'
--Property1, Property2, Property3 ...

SELECT O.PurchasedInventoryObjectID,
       O.PurchasedInventoryObjectName,
       O.PurchasedInventoryConjunctionID,
       O.Summary,
       O.Count,
       O.PropertyCount,
       O.IsActive
FROM   tblPurchasedInventoryObject As O
INNER JOIN tblPurchasedInventoryConjunction As C ON C.PurchasedInventoryConjunctionID = O.PurchasedInventoryConjunctionID
INNER JOIN tblPurchasedInventoryItem As I ON I.PurchasedInventoryItemID = C.PurchasedInventoryItemID
INNER JOIN tblPurchasedInventorySection As S ON S.PurchasedInventorySectionID = C.PurchasedInventorySectionID
INNER JOIN tblPurchasedInventoryPropertyMap as M ON M.PurchasedInventoryObjectID = O.PurchasedInventoryObjectID
INNER JOIN tblPropertyValue As V ON V.PropertyValueID = M.PropertyValueID

WHERE

I.PurchasedInventoryItemID = @PurchasedInventoryItemID AND
S.PurchasedInventorySectionID = @PurchasedInventorySectionID AND
I.PurchasingCategoryID = @PurchasedInventoryItem_PurchasingCategoryID AND
S.PurchasingCategoryID = @PurchasedInventorySection_PurchasingCategoryID AND
O.IsActive = @IsActive AND
V.PropertyID = @PropertyID AND 
V.Value = @PropertyValue
```

Now, I know that a query in .NET doesnt look like this, this is my test in the SQL Design Studio. Naturally VB.NET variables will be used in place of the SQL local variables.

My problem is this: All of the conditions after "WHERE" are optional. In that a query might be made that uses one, some, all, or none of the conditions. V.PropertyID and V.Value can also appear any number of times.

In VB.NET I can make this query easy enough by simply concatenating strings, and using a loop to append the "V.PropertyID/V.Value" conditions.

I can also make a Stored Procedure in MS SQL, which is easy enough.

However, I want to accomplish this using LINQ.

If anyone could direct me, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by string-concatenating my query and using the DataContext.ExecuteQuery function:

```
Dim res As IEnumerable(Of tblPurchasedInventoryObject) = pidc.ExecuteQuery(Of tblPurchasedInventoryObject)(query).ToList
```

Works like a charm, I can even change the data and post it back to the database. It still feels "backwards" though, and im open to better methods of doing this.

Comment: I think dynamic sql is unfortunately going to be your best bet here.  What I would do, though, is build that on the server in a stored procedure and use sp_executesql to run it.  Then you might be able to simplify your .ExecuteQuery() call to simply calling a stored procedure name.

Comment: Good thing to know, since this feels so wrong its re-assuring having someone tell me it might be my better option.

Answer (score 0):

“ In VB.NET I can make this query easy enough by simply concatenating strings, and using a loop to append the "V.PropertyID/V.Value" conditions ”

You can make the same thing by using in memory query, by building the query statement and then filter “only when it’s required” by using expression trees
Here’s basics of expression trees
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/charlie/expression-tree-basics)

and this is good article on the subject:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/generating-dynamic-methods-with-expression-trees-in-visual-studio-2010)
you can also refer to page 238 section 9.3 in Jon skeet’s book C# in depth http://www.manning.com/skeet/, and also Linq in Action book http://www.manning.com/marguerie/ all have a good explanation of Expression trees.

Comment: Awesome! I knew I'd have to learn some new things, and im relieved to see them laid out right in front of me instead of me having to burn up google again(its rough when you dunno what you're lookin for). Thank you much